# Can I change the regex engine used to search in `less`?

Tags: command-line, less, pcre

I would like to use a perl compatible regex engine in the `less` command line utility. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not out of the box. What you can do as a substitute is to send the input to `grep --perl-regexp` (or `-P`) before piping it to `less`, for example:

```
some_command | grep -P … | less
```

If you want to see the rest of the file as well, with the matches highlighted, you can use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981831/96588) and pipe the result to `less --raw-control-chars` (or `-r`).

Comment: Suspected as much, thanks for confirming. I always forget which regex idiosyncrasies apply in which command line tool, and have a bad habit to lean on Perl regex niceties ):